# Exporting data to csv python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

When I use the following code below, my data gets exported but its all in one column going all the way down, any help?

```
b = open('tester.csv', 'wb')
a = csv.writer(b)
while (count < x):
    tags = str(data['alerts'][count]  ['tags']).replace("u\"","\"").replace("u\'","\'")
a.writerows(strList)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python export csv data into file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813490/python-export-csv-data-into-file)

Comment: Where is `strList` defined?  Also, sample data would help.

Comment: What is `strList`?  It should be a collection of rows (`['r1', 'r1c2'], ['r2', 'r2c2']]`).

Comment: yes it is a collection of rows printing data like this ['hi', 'yes', 'bye', 'def']
['hi', 'ast', 'cnx', 'vplex']
['ever', 'as', 'no', 'qwerty', 'redi']
['no', 'yes', 'qwerty']
['redi', 'google']
['redi', 'asdf', 'asdfef', 'wer']
['redi', 'asd', 'rrr', 'www', 'qqq']
['erfa', 'asdf', 'fef']
['hi', 'dsa', 'f3e']

Comment: @Jsant:  That's what you think it is, but the problem you're having indicates otherwise.  Look at the output of `print strList` and you will probably find it's not a list of lists.

Comment: strList = tags.strip('[]')

Answer (score 0):

Given your data, I fail to see how this could go wrong, unless your data doesn't actually look like this.

```
>>> data = [['hi', 'yes', 'bye', 'def'], ['hi', 'ast', 'cnx', 'vplex'], ['ever', 'as', 'no', 'qwerty', 'redi'], ['no', 'yes', 'qwerty'], ['redi', 'google'], ['redi', 'asdf', 'asdfef', 'wer'], ['redi', 'asd', 'rrr', 'www', 'qqq'], ['erfa', 'asdf', 'fef'], ['hi', 'dsa', 'f3e']]
>>> with open('my.csv','w') as f:
...  for item in data:
...   my_item = item[0]+','+item[1]+'\n'
...   f.write(my_item)
...
```

pg my.csv

```
hi,yes
hi,ast
ever,as
no,yes
redi,google
redi,asdf
redi,asd
erfa,asdf
hi,dsa
(EOF):
```